# Como converter variáveis numéricas para string?

Tags: spss

Eu tenho uma série de 45 variáveis do tipo numeric que representam as respostas certas ou erradas de um conjunto de alunos (são 45 questões ao todo) e gostaria de criar uma única string com as 45 respostas e gostaria de ter uma string Q_CN com todas elas concatenadas

alguém pode ajudar? o programa que eu uso é o SPSS da IBM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
STRING  Q_CN (A45).
COMPUTE Q_CN=CONCAT(VAR00001 TO VAR00045).
EXECUTE.
```